# Concatenate Data -Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with data formatted in a .txt file in the format below:

```
family1 1 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 NA NA 4
family1 2 0 0 2 2 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 NA NA 4
family1 3 0 0 2 5 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 NA NA 2
family2 1 0 0 2 5 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 NA NA 3
etc.
```

where the second column is a member of the family and the other columns are numbers that correspond to traits. 
I need to compare the relatives listed in this data set to create an output like this:

```
family1 1 2 traitnumber traitnumber ...
family1 1 3 traitnumber traitnumber ...
family1 2 3 traitnumber traitnumber ...
```

where the numbers are the relatives.

I have created a data frame using:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt.', sep=" ", header = None)
print(data)
```

Can you offer any advice on the most efficient way to concatenate this data into the desired rows? I am having trouble comparing thinking of a way to write code for the different combinations i.e. relative 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and 2 and 3. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might find `combinations` from `itertools` to be helpful.

```
from itertools import combinations
print([thing for thing in combinations((1,2,3), 2)])
```

Yields

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you that would be helpful, but could I do that/ how would I do that since I have about 24 elements per row?

Comment: Can you offer any more advice?

Answer (score 0):

Building on DragonBobZ comment.  You could do something like this using the groupby function of the dataframe to split out the families

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header = None)
print(data)

from itertools import combinations
grouped_df = data.groupby(0)

for key, item in grouped_df:
    print key
    current_subgroup = grouped_df.get_group(key)
    print current_subgroup
    print current_subgroup.shape, "\n"
    print([thing for thing in combinations(range(current_subgroup.shape[0]), 2)])
```

Grabbing the output of the "combinations" line will give you a list of tuples that you can use in conjunction with row indexing to perform the comparisons for the appropriate columns.

Comment: Needless to say you would have to iterate over the list of tuples. :-)